# date format for NSDateFormatter

Tags: iphone, ios4, nsdateformatter

I need a date format for string Dec 31, 2010 3:20am to convert it to date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: (I havent) ;)

```
NSString *test = @"Dec 31, 2010 3:20am"
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]; 
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM dd, yyyy HH:mm a"];
NSDate *testOut = [dateFormatter dateFromString:test];
```

Comment: I think we should use MMM for month(in this case), not MM.